# Merging several worksheets by matched rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have four worksheets from World bank containing information on GDP, per capita percentage of Nurses, per capita percentage of physicians, and health expenditure for respectively 217, 198, 136, 204 countries. Here is a screenshot of part of the data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E54gg.jpg)

Is it possible to merge the sheets by keeping only the countries having data on all four indicators (136 countries in this case).

Comment: Build full list of countries on 5th sheet (copy from all 4 sheets and remove duplicates). Copy data fields from all 4 sheets to it using VLOOKUP(). Replace formulas with values using PasteSpecial. Set filter to empty/error value in at least onу data column and remove them. To automate this process you can use MacroRecorder.

Comment: Could you share part of expected output with us ??

Comment: Do you want to get table with Country GDP(m) Nurse Physician H.exp directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm assuming that all four Sheets are identical, having data in Range `A2:B13`.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- To copy Country name enter this Formula in Cell `A1` of Master Sheet & fill down.

  ```
   =INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A1,1,1)
  ```
- Create appropriate headings in respected Row.
- Write this Formula in Master Sheet's Cell `B2` & fill down.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:B13,2,FALSE),"")`

Formula in Cell `C2`:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B13,2,FALSE),"")`

**N.B.**

- Use the same Formula for other Data from different Sheets.
- Sheet Names are editable.
- Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.

**Edited:**

*To do the same job in faster way I would like to suggest few handy VBA tricks.*

- Create New Sheet and name it `MASTER`.
- Press `ALT+F11` to open VB editor.
- From the `VIEW` menu find & Click `Immediate Window`.

*Write Following VBA code lines in shown sequence.*

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("A1")
```

**Note,**

*Above code will copy Country Names in `Col A`.*

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("B1")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("C1")

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("D1")
```

**Note,**

- Above codes will copy `GDP, Physician & Hexp` columns from `Source Sheets` to `Master` and create a Table like Structure as shown in Screen Shot.

**N.B**

- Sheet Names are editable.
- Adjust Cell references in the Code as needed.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit,, glad to help you,, now you may accept my post as answer !!